# Question about Firebase phone authentication not working for German number over O2 and Deutsch Telekom

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Firebase phone authentication not working for German number over over O2 and Deutsch Telekom network

User can not able to receive OTP if he try to verify from Germany. Even  onCodeSent method is not calling.

But with same number I tried from India then user get   OTP  on respective mobile number.

On the starting User can able to get OTP  on both network(O2 and Deutsch Telekom). But now couldn't able to receive not even  onCodeSent method is calling.

[firebase]

Comment: I suggest that you reach out to the Firebase team via their [Support Contact page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact). This should work in Germany given that it is what [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#phone-auth-countries-label) suggests.

Comment: Hello we are suffering from the same issue, our application is live and it's main origin is Germany and we are lost lots of user because the user with the O2 network or the number start with +49176 does not received otp in their phone number so they can not register with our application and we couldn't find the proper solution. any help would be appreciated Thanks